# Debugging a javascript file in a mvc application and how to set it up

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

In my shared folder and _Layout.cshtml file I have this statement declared

```
@RenderSection("JavaScript", required: false)
```

In my About page I have this declared

```
@section JavaScript
{
 <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/dotty.js")"></script> 
}

<p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>

<button id="mybtn">Submit Me</button>
```

I created a file named dotty.js in the Scripts folder and it looks like this

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.10.2.min.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery-1.10.2.js" />

$('mybtn').click(function () {
alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});
```

When I run run the About page all I get is this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

My dotty.js file is not visible when I do F12 and try to step through the code. 
Please what am I missing ?

I want to be able to debug my javascript file.

Comment: The error is because you have not included `jquery-{version}.js` in the view or layout

Comment: I included this in the About page and still getting the same error message. <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

Comment: You don't need to include both the minified and unminified files, one or the other will do.

Comment: I removed one and kept the minified version but still the same error message. Can my browser be caching?

Comment: Are you placing the jQuery tag *before* your `dotty.js` tag?

Comment: Huh... I actually placed it after the tag. I will try before it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `debugger;` statement which will cause the execution of the script to break if you have the F12 developer tools open.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger)

On a related note, your error is likely due to not including the jQuery libraries in your application.